# Force mousepad to block terminal

Tags: command-line, text-editor

I'm using mousepad as my default editor. However, recently mousepad does not block the terminal when it has been called up from there. How can I restore this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update mousepad using `sudo apt-get install mousepad`, if there is no updates try to reinstall it again using `sudo apt-get remove mousepad` and then `sudo apt-get install mousepad`

Comment: Works! I had to reinstall it. Any idea what happened here or where to configure such a behavior?

Comment: You didn't provide enough informations about the problem.. so the only solution in this case is to reinstall it.

Comment: Could you be more precisely which informations are needed?